# Abstract class grandchildren inheritance

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract

I'm trying to create a (rather clumsy) little game and I've come to a problem.
I have a class tree as follows:

- Entity

  - Character

    - Player
    - Enemy
  - Static

    - Stairs
    - OtherEncounter

Now I intend to implement a generator which should generate a map based on some simple heuristics and via Entity constructor add encounters to some Tiles. For that I chose to use "*Entity e*" parameter in my Tile contructor.

Now for getting the correct type I set up a virtual method in all classes to return their exact type. That being abstract both in *Entity.cs* and *Character.cs*. But as expected, it doesn't do much good to inherit an abstract method and make it abstract again.

Thus, my question is, is there any kind of "correct" implementation or is there just some simple workaround? I could always just skip the method in *Entity.cs* and create two distinct in both *Character.cs* and *Static.cs*, but that just seems too... redneck-y.

**TL;DR:** How to inherit abstract method in grandchildren while not declaring in children.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `Character` is abstract, you don't have to implement it in `Character` at all. See this example:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public abstract string Name {get;}
}

public abstract class Child : Parent
{

}

public class Grandchild: Child
{
    public override string Name { get { return "Test"; } }
}
```

Because `Child` is also abstract, you don't need to redeclare any methods as `abstract`, so it just passes the implementation requirement onto `Grandchild`.

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/CLG94204)